# Problems saving SVG to PNG

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, png, electron

**Solved (kind of):** The problem seemed to be not due to anything in the code. As it runs fine in any web browser. The problem was something to do with the fact that I was running it in an electron shell. As to why that wasn't working I have no idea.

---

My question is not so much how to save SVG as a PNG, but instead why this one library is not working for a very specific case. The library works for converting many of my charts to PNG, but there is this one chart that just doesn't seem to succesfully save the PNG.
This is the segment of the code that appears to be the center of the problems that are occuring.

```
//Create image object
var image = new Image();


image.src = uri;
  image.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = image.width;
      canvas.height = image.height;
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.download = name;
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    };
```

The values of the variable `uri` appears to be correct in all cases, including the ones that won't ultimately save. I know this because I have saved the URI variable value to a text file. Then used an online resource that can view this type of image format.

As well I have also checked that the `a.download = name;` and `a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');` are the correct values. Which they are in all cases.

The last piece of information that I have for is that in the case that doesn't work in the save window that pops up, the file name reads "download" instead of the value `a.download = name`.

This leads me to believe that whatever bug is happening is outside of the realm of this code and maybe whatever happens when `a.click();` is called is going wrong, but I don't know how to debug that.

This is the SVG markup for the image that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="3680" height="2080" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 920 520">
<defs>
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[]]>
    </style>
</defs>
<g transform="translate(40,40)">
    <line class="xaxis" x1="0" y1="460" x2="880" y2="460" stroke="gray"></line>
    ...
    ...
    ...
 </g>
 </svg>
```

This is the SVG markup in the case that doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="2080" height="2080" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 520 520">
<defs>
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[]]>
    </style>
</defs>
<g transform="translate(40,40)">
    <circle cx="201.5" cy="201.5" r="203" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.25" fill="none"></circle>
    ...
    ...
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: When i run this code on my local machine it works fine. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: What error exactly do you get? Debug and specify. Are you saving problematic graph in the same way as others? Calling a function from other source?

Comment: We'll need to see some of your svg's markup. A common problem that could be yours is the absence of absolute `width`and `height` attributes on the root svg node. Also, you may want to attach the image's onload event **before** setting its `src`.

Comment: Hi, I am getting no console errors, which is one of the weird parts. 
What part of the SVG markup do you need to see?
So do you literally just mean:
image.onload = function () {...};
image.src = uri;

Comment: What you gave is enough to eliminate the width height part. Now, yes, you can try to set the src after setting the onload event handler, webkit browsers are known to have some difficulties to wait till the js process have finished before firing the event. And final question, which library are you using ?

Comment: Hi, I tried adding `image.src = uri;` And I guess maybe library is an overstatement. It is a single function that converts svg to png. Honestly I can't remember where I found it, I have been using it for years actually.